# The Chofetz Chayim's system of the olamos

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, nefesh-hachaim

In the sefer Toras Habayis (written by the Chofetz Chayim) in chapter 4 [the paragraph that starts with *ha'nimshal muvan me'elav*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33083&pgnum=13), he writes the hierarchy of the olamos (worlds) like this: Briyah, Yetzirah, Galgalim, Asiyah. He then says from Asiyah to the Aretz. What/Whose system is he using?

I'm only familiar with the way the Nefesh HaChaim lays it out: Atzilus, Briyah (Kisei Kevodo), Yetzira (Chayos), Asiyah (Ofanim).

Additionaly (this is not my main question), why does he say "from Asiyah to the aretz"? I thought Asiyah is the physical world?

Comment: see shaarei kedusha beginning of part 3. he also quotes from part 1 of the book at start of shemiras halashon

Comment: @ray The system explained there is Atzilus, Briyah, Yetzira, Asiyah. There is a fifth, above these, Adam Kamon (Tzachzachos) but I don't see any reference to the Chofetz Chayim's hierarchy.

Comment: look again he traces it down to the planets.